# how to get all previous called methods from first to end methods

Tags: c#, .net, function, reflection, stack-trace

Let's say we have this code

```
namespace app.Entities
{
    public class school
    {
        public bool Addschool() { }
    }
}


namespace app.layer1
{
    public class ManageSchool
    {
        public bool schoolInfo() {
            schoolInfo.addSchool();
        }
    }
}


namespace app.layer
{
    public class schoolAPi
    {
        public bool GetAndAdd()
        {
            ManageSchool.schoolInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

i want to know which layers and fuctions called AddSchool() method in  app.entitied namespace
for exp :
app.layer2.schoolAPi.GetAndAdd >> app.layer1.ManageSchool.schoolInfo >> app.Entities.school.Addschool

Comment: you can use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();`

Comment: Could you please be a bit more strict with your adherence to naming convention? In C# we use PascalCase for namespaces, classes, methods and properties. camelCase is generally for private and local members

Answer (score 0):

Try look at `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` and `System.Diagnostics.StackFrame` classes.
You can create some `Tracer` class with `Trace` method to trace each call, but you supposed to put trace in each method to be able to trace it.

Example of `Tracer.cs`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Tracer
{
    public static void Trace()
    {
        StackFrame sf = new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Called {0} in {1} at line: {2}", sf.GetMethod().ToString(), sf.GetFileName(), sf.GetFileLineNumber());
    }
}
```

Examples of your project:

`Entities.cs`:

```
namespace App.Entities
{
    public class School
    {
        public static bool AddSchool()
        {
            Tracer.Trace();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

`LayerOne.cs`:

```
using App.Entities;

namespace App.LayerOne
{
    public class ManageSchool
    {
        public static bool SchoolInfo()
        {            
            Tracer.Trace();
            School.AddSchool();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

`LayerTwo.cs`:

```
using App.LayerOne;

namespace App.LayerTwo
{
    public class SchoolAPI
    {
        public static bool GetAndAdd()
        {
            Tracer.Trace();
            ManageSchool.SchoolInfo();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And a `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using App.LayerTwo;

namespace App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Tracer.Trace();
            SchoolMethod();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SchoolMethod()
        {
            Tracer.Trace();
            SchoolAPI.GetAndAdd();                
        } 
    }
}
```

It will give you some kind of this result:
[image]

Also you can put `Tracer.Trace()` method under bool condition of some global setting and use it only when you need trace:

```
if (MySettingsClass.TraceEnabled)
    Tracer.Trace();
```